# Magento - zend - backend error

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, autoload

I get the following error when i am logged into the backend in magento

Fatal error: Interface 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Interface' not found in /homepages/45/d210005774/htdocs/**websitename**/lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php on line 176

Also i got this error previously in my index management section in magento

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Locale_Data::disableCache() in
/homepages/45/d210005774/htdocs/**websitename**/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php
on line 153

Could anyone help me out with this? I think the problem is to do with zend framework but i am not sure whats causing this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's something wrong with your installation.  Either you're missing files from Magento's lib folder, you have damaged files in Magento's lib folder, or (longshot) your PHP include path is pointing in a different location.

First thing I'd do is download a fresh install of your version of Magento, unzip it in a separate folder, and then run

```
diff -r /homepages/45/d210005774/htdocs/websitename/ /path/to/fresh/magento
```

This will give you a list of differences between the standard core files and your own.

If you want to diagnose specific files, check

```
lib/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Interface.php
```

for the missing interface

```
 interface Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Interface
 {
 ...
 }
```

And check

```
lib/Zend/Locale
```

for the missing method

```
public static function disableCache($flag)
{
    self::$_cacheDisabled = (boolean) $flag;
}
```

Finally, check you PHP include path to ensure there isn't an older copy of Magento and/or Zend being included.

Answer (score 0):

Upload Zend folder again.it works for me.